# Unknown cause of segfault using openMP

Tags: c, multithreading, gdb, openmp

I'm brand new to threading and was hoping to get some help with a problem I've encountered. I'm also new to gdb. This is my first time posting a question here, so any tips or things I should do differently are greatly appreciated.

I'm modifying a library (written in C) which is built with cmake. I've included openMP in CMakeLists.txt.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2 and I believe openMP 4.0.

To make a function in the library run faster, I wanted to use openMP to modify a for loop. Here is a snippet of the code I was working on:

```c
// now that the arrays are set the threads can be called
// each thread will handle one direction, which corresponds to one fiber
//      tenFiberContext* tfx ... for whole seed
//      tenFiberMulti* tfml ... for whole seed
//      unsigned int dirNum ... 2 for 2 tensor
//      int dirIdx ... 0 or 1 for 2 tensor
//      double* seedData ... pointer to seed voxels stored in memory
//      unsigned int seedNum ... total number of seed voxels
//      int seedIdx ... present seed voxel
//      int i ... present fiber

#
pragma omp parallel
for private(iam, np, dirIdx, seedIdx, fibrIdx, seed)
for (i = 0; i <= fibrNum - 1; i++) {
  //#pragma omp critical
  //{
  np = omp_get_num_threads();
  iam = omp_get_thread_num();
  dirIdx = dirS[i];
  seedIdx = seedNumS[i];
  fibrIdx = i;
  printf("THREAD %d OUT OF %d\ndirIdx: %d\tseedIdx: %d\tfibrIdx: %d\n", iam, np, dirIdx, seedIdx, fibrIdx);
  // tfml and tfx need to be shared

  if (tfx - > verbose > 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: dir %u/%u on seed %u/%u; len %u; # %u\n", me,
      dirIdx, dirNum, seedIdx, seedNum,
      tfml - > fiberArr - > len, fibrIdx);
  } // prints info about seed, dir, etc. if error

  if (tfml - > fiberArr - > len == fibrIdx) {
    airArrayLenIncr(tfml - > fiberArr, 1);
  } // builds airArray in tfml for all fibers as it goes

  ELL_3V_COPY(tfml - > fiber[fibrIdx].seedPos, seedData + 3 * seedIdx);
  tfml - > fiber[fibrIdx].dirIdx = dirIdx;
  tfml - > fiber[fibrIdx].dirNum = dirNum;
  ELL_3V_COPY(seed, seedData + 3 * seedIdx);

  if (tenFiberSingleTrace(tfx, & (tfml - > fiber[fibrIdx]), seed, dirIdx)) {
    biffAddf(TEN, "%s: trouble on seed (%g,%g,%g) %u/%u, dir %u/%u", me,
      seed[0], seed[1], seed[2], seedIdx, seedNum, dirIdx, dirNum);
  }
  if (tfx - > verbose) {
    if (tenFiberStopUnknown == tfml - > fiber[fibrIdx].whyNowhere) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: (%g,%g,%g) ->\n"
        "   steps = %u,%u; len = %g,%g;"
        "whyStop = %s,%s\n", me, seed[0], seed[1], seed[2],
        tfml - > fiber[fibrIdx].stepNum[0],
        tfml - > fiber[fibrIdx].stepNum[1],
        tfml - > fiber[fibrIdx].halfLen[0],
        tfml - > fiber[fibrIdx].halfLen[1],
        airEnumStr(tenFiberStop,
          tfml - > fiber[fibrIdx].whyStop[0]),
        airEnumStr(tenFiberStop, tfml - > fiber[fibrIdx].whyStop[1]));
    } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: (%g,%g,%g) -> whyNowhere: %s\n",
        me, seed[0], seed[1], seed[2],
        airEnumStr(tenFiberStop,
          tfml - > fiber[fibrIdx].whyNowhere));
    } //else
  } // if
  //}

} // for
```

Threading does commence and a few threads complete before it segfaults at the line:

```
ELL_3V_COPY(tfml->fiber[fibrIdx].seedPos, seedData + 3*seedIdx);
```

I've tried different combinations of private variables including none but it still results in a segfault.

Here is a snippet of the error after running it in gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  [Switching to Thread 0x7fffd7b37700(LWP 8848)]
0x00000000005a1841 in tenFiberMultiTrace._omp_fn.0() at / home / jasmine / apps / teem / src / ten / fiber.c: 1179
1179 ELL_3V_COPY(tfml - > fiber[fibrIdx].seedPos, seedData + 3 * seedIdx);
(gdb)
Continuing.
THREAD 7 OUT OF 12
dirIdx: 1 seedIdx: 13 fibrIdx: 27
THREAD 9 OUT OF 12
dirIdx: 1 seedIdx: 16 fibrIdx: 33[Thread 0x7fffd7b37700(LWP 8848) exited]
  [Thread 0x7fffd8b39700(LWP 8846) exited]
  [Thread 0x7fffd933a700(LWP 8845) exited]
  [Thread 0x7fffd9b3b700(LWP 8844) exited]
  [Thread 0x7fffda33c700(LWP 8843) exited]
  [Thread 0x7fffdab3d700(LWP 8842) exited]
  [Thread 0x7fffdb33e700(LWP 8841) exited]
  [Thread 0x7fffdbb3f700(LWP 8840) exited]
  [Thread 0x7fffdc340700(LWP 8839) exited]
  [Thread 0x7fffdcb41700(LWP 8838) exited]
  [Thread 0x7ffff7fd77c0(LWP 8834) exited]
Cannot find user - level thread
for LWP 8847: generic error(gdb)
Continuing.
Cannot execute this command without a live selected thread.
```

At first the int arrays dirS and seedNumS were automatic, so I allocated memory for them and the segfault still occurred. My understanding is that tfx, tfml, seedData, and seedNum are shared, which I want them to be so that each thread can access them at the same point in memory. Also, tfx and tfml are pointers to structs declared in a header file included in the library. There are also many references in the code snippet to functions elsewhere in the library.

I commented this out in the code snippet, but I also tried making all the contents of the loop critical, which did not work. The code runs fine if I run it on one thread without using openMP.

I've read that static variables could be the culprit, but don't understand why. Could the problem be that there are some static variables in the library which one of the functions I call uses? And why would this be a problem? I've also read that perhaps there is not enough room on the stack, but also don't know why this would prevent the critical section from working while a single thread approach is fine. Could this be the problem? And how would I go about fixing it?

Please let me know if you need any more information or clarification. Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: The library I'm using is teem by the way. If there are any tools you can suggest for debugging this that would be great too. Thanks.

Comment: *Please* do not put an internal space in the `->` operator.  It makes your code very hard to read.  It's pretty unconventional to put spaces *around* that operator, too, but that's not as much of a readability issue.

Comment: A segfault normally arises from a program attempting to access memory that does not belong to it.  Use of uninitialized or corrupted pointers or of pointers to freed memory are common sources, but perhaps the most common source of all is an attempt to access outside the bounds of a dynamically-allocated data structure.  Since `tfml` and `tfml->fiber` seem to be a valid pointers, I would look into the possibility that the memory block to which `tfml->fiber` points is smaller than your code actually requires.

Comment: You could also consider building and running without OpenMP to see whether you can reproduce the error that way.  If you can do so, then that will greatly simplify your debugging efforts.

Comment: Sorry about the spacing issue (I think it happened when I copied and pasted the code). Thank you for your response. If I comment out the #pragma line so that the for loop runs ordinarily there is no error. I will try taking openMP completely out of CMakeLists.txt though. I will also look into tfml more closely and get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: When I took out openMP from CMakeLists.txt there were no errors. I tried allocating memory for tfml and tfml->fiber, but the segfault still occurs at the same line after I use multiple threads again. However, with the memory allocation, it works fine with one thread. Could the pointers still be too small if I malloced them? And, why would this only be an issue when I use multiple threads?